# How to launch a published ASP.NET Angular application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have an Angular application that's managed by an ASP.NET application like [in the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). In the development environment I can do `dotnet run` from within the ASP.NET's project directory. This then builds both projects and outputs

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5273
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Dev\MyApp\src\MyApp.Client\
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
      No SPA development server running at https://localhost:44459 found.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
      SPA development server running at 'https://localhost:44459'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware[0]
      SPA proxy is ready. Redirecting to https://localhost:44459
```

A development script is ran and either port 5273 or port 44459 will redirect to the actual Angular application.

But when I run `dotnet publish --configuration test` and then run `dotnet bin/test/net6.0/MyApp.Client.dll` the ASP.NET application is served, but navigating to the port just returns a 404. How do I actually run the application in a way that serves the Angular application on a given port exactly like in development? Do I need to run the ASP.NET application and then manually serve the Angular application's built files?

My csproj is below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44459</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="6.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
  
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration production" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/27438) for discussion.

Make sure that you run `dotnet <yourAppName>.dll` from within the published folder. For example if you ran `dotnet publish --configuration test` (assuming you are in your project root):

`cd bin/test/net6.0/publish`

`dotnet <yourAppName>.dll`

Comment: When I run `dotnet publish` the angular app dll isn't created.